# Migrate some data from MySQL to MSSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a MySQL database. 
I need to migrate some (not all) table's data (data records) from MySQL to MSSQL database, herewith convert structure of MySQL tables to new structure in MSSQL.

In future, I need to do automatic periodical synchronization between these databases.
Is there any tools? or I have to use some SQL proc's or queries? How can I do these things?

For reference: I'm using MSSQL Server 2008 R2 with ODBC driver for MySQL and SQL Migration Assistant for MySQL (with these tools, I have been fully converted MySQL to MSSQL database only).

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have full SQL 2008, open the Visual Studio Intelligence BI installed with your SQL installation.
Then create a new project "Integration Services Project".

Therefor you create a new connection to your ODBC (should be wizards available).
Then add your tables, there you can modify, convert, tranasform the data.

The complete project you can save and add as sheduled task to your sql server agent.

Here is a tutorial which explains more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx