# Mysql to SQL Server 2008

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, joomla

Am using Joomla 1.3 for one of my client website. and now I want to move it to custom asp.net application with SQL Server 2008.

What's the best opensource to handle this migration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In other context this answer is answered here: [Migrate some data from MySQL to MSSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486346/migrate-some-data-from-mysql-to-mssql/8486392#8486392)

---

Since you already have full SQL 2008, open the Visual Studio Intelligence BI installed with your SQL installation. Then create a new project "Integration Services Project".

Therefor you create a new connection to your ODBC (should be wizards available). Then add your tables, there you can modify, convert, tranasform the data.

The complete project you can save and add as sheduled task to your sql server agent.

Here is a tutorial which explains more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx

---